# Android HAL .so not build

Tags: android-source, hal

I was following [this guide](https://github.com/jchuang1977/android8-hal-sample) to learn HAL layer and framework layer in AOSP. I've managed to run the whole process. But there's one small issue. When I build the whole ROM/Android, **hello.default.so won't be built/shown up in the following**,

- ${output}/system/lib/hw
- ${output}/system/lib64/hw
- ${output}/vendor/lib/hw
- ${output}/vendor/lib64/hw

**Only by manually executing `mmm hardware/libhardware/modules/hello/`, can I get the hello.default.so.**

I have remember to append the module into `PRODUCT_PACKAGES` macro as following. Packages/Modules vim, hello-lkm-client have been successfully integrated. But not the hello.default module.

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \
    vim
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \
    hello-lkm-client
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \
    hello.default
```

Here's the Android.mk file for the hello HAL

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_RELATIVE_PATH := hw
LOCAL_PROPRIETARY_MODULE := true
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := liblog
#############
# I'm following $hw/modules/gralloc/Android.mk 
#############
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE := false
# LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := hardware/libhardware

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello.c
LOCAL_HEADER_LIBRARIES := libhardware_headers

LOCAL_MODULE := hello.default
# LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Here's the [complete](https://github.com/changxiangzhong/rockpi4-hardware-libhardware/commit/be62f78d56d9d20d853ef8b8de62c83974a95207) hello HAL module.

Answer (score 0):

OK, found it. I have to add the hello module in Android.mk of Module **modules**, just like the following.

```
chang@ryzen:~/bulk2/rockpi4-atv9-chang/hardware/libhardware$ git diff
diff --git a/modules/Android.mk b/modules/Android.mk
index a430a650..7bbeaeb9 100644
--- a/modules/Android.mk
+++ b/modules/Android.mk
@@ -2,5 +2,6 @@ hardware_modules := \
     camera \
     gralloc \
     sensors \
-    hw_output
+    hw_output \
+       hello
```